# How to get product data, if the customer has non-signed products, but there are closing products

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, having-clause

[image]there is a product table that has client_id and status_id fields
how to get a client whose status does not have a product status signed and has a closed product status

```
products
  id
  client_id
  status_id
```

Comment: Can you provide the data and expected result?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/sxvuwb

Comment: What is an identifier to understand if it is closed or signed?

Comment: id is status_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, your question suggests aggregation and a `having` clause for filtering. Assuming that `status_id` `1` is signed and `2` is closed, that would be:

```
select client_id
from products
group by client_id
having max(status_id = 1) = 0 and max(status_id = 2) = 1
```